# Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where n is a positive integer.

Tags: linear-algebra

I should solve the following question:
Find formulas for the entries of Mn, where n is a positive integer.

where M=
$$
\begin{bmatrix}11&-2\\4&5\end{bmatrix}
$$
I found the eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors, and I don't know what to do next.

$$
Eigenvalue: 9λ, multiplicity: 1λ, eigenvector: \begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
Eigenvalue: 7λ, multiplicity: 1λ, eigenvector: \begin{bmatrix}0.5&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You surely mean $M^n$, the $n$th power of $M$.  Do you know that $M^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ where the columns of $P$ are theeigenvectors you have found and $D$ diagonal with the eigenvalues you found ? It remains to compute $P^{-1}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from what you did that\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}9&0\\0&7\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}11&-2\\4&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}11&-2\\4&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}and that therefore$$\begin{bmatrix}11&-2\\4&5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}9&0\\0&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}.$$So\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}11&-2\\4&5\end{bmatrix}^n&=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}9&0\\0&7\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}9^n&0\\0&7^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}2\times9^n-7^n & 7^n-9^n \\ 2\left(9^n-7^n\right)& 2\times7^n-9^n\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}